# Weird integral symbol : $\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!-}$

Tags: integration, notation

What does this integral sign mean ($\int$ with line going through the middle)?

$$
\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}
$$

(It had something to do with the Beckenbach-Radó Theorem)

Comment: There are examples [here](http://www.helsinki.fi/~marola/julkaisuja/EKMS.pdf) and [here](http://math.uark.edu/SLS-10-Marola.pdf), but without definition...

Comment: This can also be found in Appendix E.4 of PDE by Evans

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One common usage of this symbol is *average*: The integral divided by the measure of the domain of integration.

Comment: Appears in Abramowitz and Stegun [1964, although I have the 10th printing], (Chapter 5, Exponential Integrals, Eq. 5.1.2 and 5.1.3). Namely Ei(x) = - [funny integral with line] exp(-t)/t dt. The limits are (-x) to +infinity, (x real), so I don't see how an "average" would be possible over an infinite interval....?

Comment: @Atomique In that case, I think it could refer to the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral. Note that you are integrating past a singularity at $t=0$ where the function is not integrable in the classical sense.

Answer (score 5):

Also used for the Cauchy Principal Value of an integral.